npm Express 4.18.2, 4.19.2 throwing high vulnerability
I create an empty NodeJS project very minimal to investigate high vulnerability message i get when I run npm i to build dependencies.
here is the basic package.json.
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "test.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  },
  "description": ""
}

When i run npm i on this project, i get following message:

up to date, audited 65 packages in 532ms
12 packages are looking for funding
run npm fund for details
2 high severity vulnerabilities*
To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force
Run npm audit for details.

Obviously, i run npm audit fix --force and it can't fix it, it tries to downgrade Express to 3.21 but bring even more vulnerabilities.
Info: i have been working with NodeJS and Express for the last year and i have other NodeJS projects working fine with Express 4.18.2.
Any idea why it is now broken and npm not able to build with Express 4.18.2.  I tried 4.19.2 and I am getting same issue.
Any feedback appreciated.
tried
npm audit fix --force 

as suggested but 2 high vulnerability thrown.

Well, for some reasons, tried today and got different results:
*> up to date, audited 65 packages in 338ms

12 packages are looking for funding   run npm fund for details
2 high severity vulnerabilities
To address all issues, run:   npm audit fix
Run npm audit for details.*

npm audit fix 

resolved the vulnerability issue:
% npm audit fix

added 5 packages, removed 1 package, changed 5 packages, and audited 69 packages in 985ms

14 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

Yesterday both "npm audit fix" and "npm audit fix --force" couldn't resolve the vulnerability issue.
Still not understanding what went wrong with npm... anyway issue is resolved.
Thx
